# Recommendations for running a local nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I have a domain and a web-app written in PHP running on Ubuntu 12.04. When a user registers, I would like to give that user a unique subdomain which needs to resolve to an IP independently of the website (meaning I can't just do a redirect with a wildcarded subdomain).

I'm guessing I need to run a local nameserver to make this possible. Could anyone recommend some nameserver software that would allow me to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: After chatting with a sysadmin, I've been pointed to BIND (https://www.isc.org/software/bind).

Comment: We typically don't do product recommendations on ServerFault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerDNS or myDNS should help achieve this, they both work with MySQL and a number of other databases, so inserting records from PHP is easily done.
Bind is also an option however writing out/updating zone records for bind from PHP is somewhat harder.

Comment: Thank you Flash - that's a really helpful answer. I think I'll avoid ServerFault in the future though. Seems you have to know the answer to ask the question.